# Get value option page ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created an ACF option page, all went good. I created some custom fields, once again all went good. I also saved data in the fields, all went good.

I looked in the database and it was saved under `wp_options`, so all went good.

Now I wan't to get the values in an php script on the backend.

Let's say my field name is `field_name`.

I used `get_field('field_name', 'option');`, it didn't give me anything.

I also tried `get_fields();` - this gave me an array with the option fields like this:

```
array(3) { 
  ["field_name"]=> array(0) { } 
  ["field_name1"]=> bool(false) 
  ["field_name2"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

So, somehow the values are empty.

I checked the database again, but they're there.

```
$field = get_field_object('field_879e859f07841');
var_dump(get_post_meta ( $field['key'], 'field_name'));
```

This gave the same empty array..

I can't figure this out.

Can someone help with figuring what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [ACF Get values](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/)

To Display a field:

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name', 'option'); ?></p>
```

To retrieve a field as a variable:

```
<?php

$variable = get_field('field_name', 'option');

// do something with $variable

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time ago since I asked this question. I'm using the plugin Timber now which I love!

You can get the values in the standard php file like this:

```
$context['site_copyright_info'] = get_field('copyright_info', 'options');
Timber::render('index.twig', $context); '
```

The plugin renders a .twig page where you easily can use the values like this:

```
<footer>{{copyright_info}}</footer>
```

thanks for contribution all!